# javascript async/await в while

Tags: javascript, циклы, async-await, while

Нужно, чтобы цикл дожидался завершения функции Func2, или как минимум таймаута, затем повторял итерацию, и так до бесконечности:

```
const mm = require('music-metadata');
async function Func1()
{
  do {
    console.log('before');
    await Func2();
    console.log('after');
    setTimeout(() => {}, 3000);
  } while (1);
}

async function Func2()
{
  httpGet(Url, {native: true}).then(async metadata => {
    // Parse the audio stream
    const mimeType = metadata.headers['content-type'];
    console.log('Parsing: ' + mimeType);

    await mm.parseStream(metadata, mimeType, {native: false, skipPostHeaders: true }).then(function(){
      console.log('Done');
    });
  }).catch(function (err) {
    // Oops, something went wrong
    console.error(err.message);
  });
}

function httpGet (url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      http.get(url, function (res) {
        switch (res.statusCode) {
          case 200:
            resolve(res);
            break;
          case 302: // redirect
            resolve(httpGet(res.headers.location));
            break;
          default:
            reject(new Error('Unexpected status-code:' + res.statusCode));
        }
      });
    });
}

Func1();
```

Но while ни в какую не хочет останавливаться, в консоль сразу вылетает миллион before after. Что я делаю не так? И есть ли более современный/этичный способ чтоб функция повторяла сама себя после отработки (при этом отработавшие копии должны удаляться из памяти)?

Comment: Покажите код для `Func2`. Также `Func1` надо вызывать  как `await Func1()`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko если вызывать Func1() вне какой-либо async функции, ругается: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: Все правильно ругается. Поэтому надо смотреть полный ваш код, а не отрывки. Только в таком случае можно дать полноценный верный ответ.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Дополнил пост всеми сопутствующими функциями.

Comment: У вас `Func2` не возвращает промис. Сделайте `return httpGet` или `await httpGet`. И по стилю - у вас смешение промисов и `async\await`. Используйте что-то одно.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Понял. А что насчет второго вопроса, есть ли более элегантный способ зациклить выполнение функции? Может как-то через `then`?

Comment: Можно через рекурсию, но особых преимуществ способ через рекурсию не имеет в вашем случае.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо, что бы `Func2` возвращал промис.

Посмотрите пример.

```js
console.clear();
async function Func1() {
  let i = 0;
  do {
    console.log('before');
    await Func2();
    console.log('after');
    i++;
  } while (i < 2);
}

async function Func2() {
  try {
    const metadata = await httpGet('url');
    console.log('Done', metadata);
  } catch (err) {
    // Oops, something went wrong
    console.error(err.message);
  }
}

async function httpGet(url) {
  return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('response'), 2000); // симулируем запрос
  });
}

Func1();
```

Способ зацикливания через рекурсию

```js
console.clear();
async function Func2() {
  try {
    const metadata = await httpGet('url');
    console.log('Done', metadata);
  } catch (err) {
    // Oops, something went wrong
    console.error(err.message);
  }
  Func2();
}

async function httpGet(url) {
  return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('response'), 2000); // симулируем запрос
  });
}

Func2();
```

Comment: Если через рекурсию - не получится ли так, что создаются копии функции в функции, при этом "родительские" копии останутся висеть в памяти?

Comment: @Лев Копии функций не создаются. Функция вообще одна в памяти и каждый новый вызов никакой копии функции не создает. Вот переменные в функции - другое дело)

Answer (score 2):

Всё ОК , ты просто забыл setTimeout в Promise обернуть

```js
async function Func1()
{
  let i = 0;
  do {
    console.log('before');
    await Func2();
    console.log('after');
    i++;
  } while (i < 10);
}
async function Func2() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(), 3000);
  })
}
Func1();
```

Comment: Да, вы правы. А что насчет второго вопроса, есть ли более элегантный способ зациклить выполнение функции? Может как-то через `then`?

Comment: @Лев вообще можно вызывать асинхронную функцию рекурсивно
` async function F() { await F() }  `
и если надо таймаут внутри принудительно то 
` async function F() { 
await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(), 3000);
  })
await F() 
}  `